# XML content of View on storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I'm trying to modify the XML file of my View's controller to edit the size of UIPickerView.

However, I have used the storyboard instead of individual xib files. How do I open the XML content now? I can't see an option anywhere.

Comment: You should not need to modify the XML of the storyboard directly. To change the size of something, change its size in code.

Comment: @mattt: I'm trying to change the height of UIPicker, which apparently isn't resizable. I tried changing from the XML file too, it shows the effect on the story board, but when I simulate it, it's still the same size.

Comment: "I'm trying to change the height of UIPicker, which apparently isn't resizable" Dude, listen to yourself. If it isn't resizable, then that means you can't change the height! What I find is that you get a range between about 162 and 180, but (as I said) you'll need to set that in code.